# PyCharm: How to run syncdb and sql commands?

Tags: django, pycharm

When working with Django you can sync the database like this:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

and also check the created SQL like this:

```
python manage.py sql bookmarks
```

How do I do the above thorugh the PyCharm IDE instead of the terminal?

Thanks,

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`Tools` | `Run manage.py Task...`:
[image]

Comment: +1 because I did not know SO allowed for pictures embedded in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take the instructions for running the [test suite](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-django-test.html) and modify it for you own commands.  Also, see the generic [setup guide](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html).

Comment: sorry I dont see how this answers my question

Answer (score 1):

The above dialog can also be called by keybindings. CTRL ALT R on Windows and ALT R on a Mac